# Como criar uma trigger que armazena uma tupla em uma tabela quando outra tabela é atualizada?

Tags: sql, firebird

Preciso criar uma trigger para armazenar numa tabela de histórico as informações do empregado todas as vezes que ocorrer uma alteração de salário. A trigger deverá fazer a atualização do histórico, somente quando o salário for alterado.

A trigger que eu criei faz isso, porém preenche a tabela HISTORICO com outras tuplas iguais, diferindo apenas o atributo idEmpregado, ou seja, como se tivesse alterado o salário de todos os empregados.

Segue abaixo minha tentativa (deixei comentadas minhas tentativas para corrigir o erro).

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_HISTORICO_UPDATE FOR EMPREGADO
 ACTIVE 
 AFTER UPDATE 
 POSITION 0 
AS 
BEGIN 
    if(old.SALARIO != new.SALARIO) then
    begin
        if(old.SALARIO < new.SALARIO) then
        begin
            INSERT INTO HISTORICO (username, dataHoraLancamento, IDEMPREGADO, salarioAnterior, salarioAtual, situacao)
            SELECT  current_user, current_timestamp, IDEMPREGADO, old.SALARIO, new.SALARIO, 'Aumento'
            FROM    EMPREGADO;
            --WHERE   EMPREGADO.IDEMPREGADO = IDEMPREGADO;
            
            --DELETE FROM HISTORICO H WHERE H.IDEMPREGADO != IDEMPREGADO;
            
            --UPDATE HISTORICO H
            --SET H.IDEMPREGADO = IDEMPREGADO
            --WHERE H.DATAHORALANCAMENTO = current_timestamp;
        end
        else if(old.SALARIO > new.SALARIO) then
        begin
            INSERT INTO HISTORICO (username, dataHoraLancamento, IDEMPREGADO, salarioAnterior, salarioAtual, situacao)
            SELECT  current_user, current_timestamp, IDEMPREGADO, old.SALARIO, new.SALARIO, 'Redução'
            FROM    EMPREGADO;
            --WHERE   EMPREGADO.IDEMPREGADO = IDEMPREGADO;
            
            --DELETE FROM HISTORICO H WHERE H.IDEMPREGADO != IDEMPREGADO;
            
            --UPDATE HISTORICO H
            --SET H.IDEMPREGADO = IDEMPREGADO
            --WHERE H.DATAHORALANCAMENTO = current_timestamp;
        end
    end
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não é necessário o Select na tabela Empregado já que todos os valores para o Insert estão disponíveis, e acho que utilizando um Case é possível utilizar apenas um Insert:

```
if(old.SALARIO != new.SALARIO) then
begin
    INSERT INTO HISTORICO 
        (username, 
         dataHoraLancamento, 
         IDEMPREGADO, 
         salarioAnterior, 
         salarioAtual, 
         situacao)
    VALUES 
        (current_user, 
         current_timestamp, 
         old.IDEMPREGADO, 
         old.SALARIO, 
         new.SALARIO, 
         case when old.SALARIO < new.SALARIO then 'Aumento' else 'Redução' end);
end
```

Se por acaso for necessário o Select em alguma tabela, adicione um filtro para relacionar o resultado com a linha alterada utilizando os prefixos old ou new.